# What to do with common attributes in all objects, and common attributes in some objects

Tags: java, conceptual

I am creating a trading card inventory logger for my significant other, and I'm having difficulties with understanding has to best approach this problem:

- With many of the cards, there are *11 attributes* that are shared across the board. *No card does not have these attributes.*
- There are 7 types of cards that share *6 attributes*, that the other classifications of cards do not share.

**What I have currently:**

- I have an abstract class that is being used to house the 11 attributes that are universally shared.
- I have incorporated the other 6 attributes into separate, concrete classes.

**What I was thinking of doing:**

- Creating an abstract class that holds the fundamentals of all of the cards
- Creating another abstract class that holds the 6 attributes that are used by the 7 types of cards as discussed above.
- Creating smaller classes for edge cases, such as one type of card having two attributes not found in any of the other cards

Is there something else that I could do? This is simply a data class that stores information on each card, and I'd rather not have to worry about handling null if i put all of these into the same class.
I can provide a GitHub link as necessary, but I'd prefer not to, because I was chastised on reddit by many whom are passionate about the game that I am making the inventory application for.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good start.

I'm not sure if the classes need to be abstract, and that you need sub-classes for every card type. You could share the same class for different card types, and have somewhere a builder pattern to create the correct implementation for a given card type.

See https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder

You might also look at the strategy pattern to assign logic to different card types without putting all logic inside card type subclasses.

See https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy

Comment: Bless your soul. I took a design patterns class this year for uni and since i understand these a bit this makes total sense. Thank you so much. I'll update to see how it goes.